# itemArray.sortOn("y"); on my 3d carousel gave me improper result

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, carousel

i'm working on my for my 3d carousel project..my problem is when the movieclip in itemArray is clicked its supposed to load the proper swf according to filesNames array..but it doesn't..i've run through the script and found that the sortOn("y") is the caused..and i knew it should be there for the carousel to rotate properly..somebody please help me on this..

```
var centerX:Number = stage.stageWidth / 2;
var centerY:Number = stage.stageHeight / 2;
var radiusX:Number = 180;
var radiusY:Number = 50;
var speed:Number = 0.1;
var minSpeed:Number = -0.15;
var maxSpeed:Number = 0.15;
var rangeSpeed:Number = maxSpeed - minSpeed;
var minY:Number = centerY - radiusY;
var maxY:Number = centerY + radiusY;
var rangeY:Number = maxY - minY;
var minScale:Number = 0.5;
var maxScale:Number = 1.2;
var rangeScale:Number = maxScale - minScale;
var my_loader:Loader = new Loader();
var itemArray:Array =[perkhidmatan, misi, tentang, members];
var fileNames : Array = ["perkhidmatan.swf", "misi.swf", "tentang.swf","members.swf",];


var canvas:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(canvas);

for (var i:Number = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
{
canvas.addChild(itemArray[i]);
itemArray[i].buttonMode = true;
itemArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToURL);
itemArray[i].itemAngle = Math.PI * 2 / itemArray.length * i;
itemArray[i].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate);
}

function goToURL(e:MouseEvent):void {
for (var i:int = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
    if (e.currentTarget == itemArray[i]) {
        my_loader.load(new URLRequest(fileNames[i]));
        trace(fileNames[i]);
        trace(my_loader);
        addChild(my_loader);
        itemArray[i].mouseEnabled = false;
        itemArray[i].alpha = 0.5;
    } else {
        itemArray[i].mouseEnabled = true;
        itemArray[i].alpha = 1;
    }
}
}

function animate(e:Event):void
{
speed = mouseX / stage.stageWidth * rangeSpeed + minSpeed;
e.currentTarget.x = Math.cos(e.currentTarget.itemAngle) * radiusX + centerX;
e.currentTarget.y = Math.sin(e.currentTarget.itemAngle) * radiusY + centerY;
e.currentTarget.itemAngle += speed;
itemArray.sortOn("y");




for(var i:Number = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
{
    canvas.setChildIndex(itemArray[i], i);
    var pct:Number = (itemArray[i].y - minY) / rangeY;
    var scale:Number = pct * rangeScale + minScale;
    itemArray[i].scaleX = itemArray[i].scaleY = scale;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is that your array is not being sorted correctly, try `itemArray.sortOn("y", Array.NUMERIC)` instead.

It appears that your actual issue is that you're sorting one of your arrays, and then attempting to use the index from that array to access an element from another array.

You should probably give the items in your `itemArray` instance names, that way, instead of looking up the item by index, you can do away with your array containing the filenames and do something like this instead:

```
function goToURL(e:MouseEvent):void {
    my_loader.load(new URLRequest(e.currentTarget.name + ".swf"));
    addChild(my_loader);
    // ... the rest of your code goes here
}
```

Comment: tq very very very much...it works all fine!!..muaaachhhhsss!!

Comment: then how should i disabled and reduce the alpha of the item when its clicked?

Comment: If the answer helped you out, I'd appreciate if you mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: how to unload the loaded swf when the close button is clicked.(the close button is inside the loaded swf)